# Structuremap class library module

Tags: c#, service, dependency-injection, autofac, structuremap

I have a class Library containing some services.

Using structure map i want these services to be registered in that class library. This results in assemblies using this class library should not set dependencies up for this class library but simply call a module that sets this up within the library itself.

For example is this possible to do using autofac. Lets say i have a class library with IAAAService and IBBBService. Using autofac i can in this class library do the following:

```
public class AutofacModule : Module
{
    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.RegisterType<AAAService>().As<IAAAService>();
        builder.RegisterType<BBBService>().As<IBBBService>();
    }
}
```

And from the assembly that should use the library i can do this:

```
builder.RegisterModule(new AutofacModule());
```

I am in a situation where i am bound to use structure map and i want to do something similar.

Is this possible in structure map? If so how would i do that?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In StructureMap, there is a similar concept called a Registry. Take a look here for more details: http://structuremap.github.io/registration/

Please note though that I do not recommend that you use the container inside your class libraries. Containers should only be used inside applications ([if they are to be used at all](http://yacoubsoftware.blogspot.com/2015/08/why-di-containers-fail-with-complex.html)).

Quoting from [this article](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/):

> A DI Container should only be referenced from the Composition Root. All other modules should have no reference to the container.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and suggestions, very helpful.